# Escape colon in curl with -u option

Tags: curl

I can't wrap my head around how to escape semicolon in username while making a GET request.

```
curl -u testclient:sdtest1:pass -XGET -H "Content-type:application/json" \
http://localhost:8081/hello
```

But the server says that credentials are invalid. How can I escape this?

Comment: One thing, those aren't semicolons. `;` is a semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I escape a special character in a username while making a GET request.

Find the hexidecimal value of the value to be escaped, and prefix it with `%`.

So in your case, use the following:

```
curl -u testclient%3A:sdtest1:pass ...
```

> "Is there any way that I can specify a username containing a colon"
>
> "user:name:password" => "user%3Aname:password"

Source [Specifying colon in authentication username](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2007-09/0016.html)